# How to find list items that are not in another list?

Tags: python-3.x

For example i have 2 lists:

```py
a = ['podcast', 'podcasts', 'history', 'gossip', 'finance', 'business', 'kids', 'motivation', 'news', 'investing']
b = ['podcast', 'history', 'gossip', 'finance', 'kids', 'motivation', 'investing']
```

I want to find items in list `a` that are not in the list `b`

I try to do it like this:

```py
c = []
for _ in a:
    if _ not in b:
        c.append(_)
```

All that I try ends with something like this:
[image]

Initially, I have a text file with keywords:

```
podcast
podcasts
history
gossip
finance
```

Also for almost all keywords I have text files with information:

```
podcast.txt
podcasts.txt
history.txt
```

I need to find which files I am missing
I load a list of keywords like this:

```py
a = []
with open("keywords.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read().split("\n")
    for k in text:
        a.append(k)
b = [e.replace(".txt", "") for e in os.listdir("profiles/")]
```

Comment: `[i for i in a if i not in b]`

Comment: `c=[el for el in a if el not in b]`. Not worth answering

Comment: I mean...I'm just eye balling this, and I feel like this works. What's the problem?

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting I do not know why this does not work for me

Comment: @kshnkvn I just ran this, and it works. What error are you getting?

Comment: Looking at your other comments on other answers, it appears you have more code you're not showing us. I copy pasted your code and it leaves me with `c` as `['podcasts', 'business', 'news']`...

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting updated a question

Comment: @kshnkvn You're messing up the "flow" man! lol, This question "How to find list items that are not in another list?" has been answered before, so this was marked as a duplicate. Your best bet now is to delete this question, and make another post describing this issue at hand (not the duplicate list problem, your code solved that already!).

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting yes, my question is how to find elements from one list which are not in another list and not one solution does not work for me. what is the problem?

Comment: @kshnkvn I'm trying to help you. No one can answer your question *here* because it was marked as a duplicate. Your core question of "how to find items in a list that aren't in another" has already been answered on stack overflow, and your original code actually works for you. If you're still getting an empty list for `c`, that means you have more going on. You need to delete this question, and post another with more detail. There is more going on in your code that you don't realize, and that's okay, we'll help you! We just need all the code. I see you posted more, but it's already closed! gl!

Comment: Also, use a more descriptive question name on the next one, this same question name will get your question closed quick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using numpy?

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [.....]
list2 = [.....] 
diff = np.setdiff1d(list2,list1)
```

Comment: array([], dtype='<U22')

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
c = (set(a) - set(b))
```

Comment: not working. empty set

Comment: You sure? I just plugged this into a console and it worked fine for me.                    a = ['podcast', 'podcasts', 'history', 'gossip', 'finance', 'business', 'kids', 'motivation', 'news', 'investing']
b = ['podcast', 'history', 'gossip', 'finance', 'kids', 'motivation', 'investing']

c = (set(a) - set(b))
print(c)

Comment: yes, im sure, its not work

Comment: @Mike kshnkvn has more going on than what is revealed in the question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by empty set? Is that what is being returned for you, or are you getting an error?

Comment: Updated a question

Answer (score 8):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
 c = [i for i in a if i not in b]
 print(c)
 ['podcasts', 'business', 'news']
```

Comment: empty list. dont work for me